# Retrieve last inserted id from a table

Tags: php

I have a table that I would like to retrieve and display the next auto-increment 'id' attribute.

`$id = mysql_insert_id();` works AFTER insert. Though I want to display this information without inserting anything.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You can select the largest id, and then +1

Comment: get  

 $id = mysql_insert_id()+1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

**EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT id+1 as YOUR_LAST_INSERTED_ID FROM `example_table` order by id desc limit 1
```